# iOS 9 “fbauth2” missing from Info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
FBSDKLog: fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0
```

Any idea what this is? I have added it in my plist but did not work.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

You can continue to use URL schemes when you build your app for iOS 9 and you want to call URL schemes, you will now need to declare them in your apps Info.plist. There is a new key, **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**, and here you will need to add the list of schemes you want to are canOpenURL on.

[image: Try like this.]

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks, lad. I thought that it would only be necessary if I was building it to a iOS9 device.

Comment: xml copy/paste version please :D ?

Comment: Why this information isn't shown on the quickstart for iOS ? https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/926602334080849/?platform=ios

Comment: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes - so you can copy paste instead of copying off the screen

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski I don't know why it's not in the quickstart guide but I found it in the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 25):

If you are using iOS9 then this is important to update your info.plist file.
You just need to do 3 steps
1. Go to info.plist
2. Add a field namely **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** NSArray datatype.
3. Add an item of NSString datatype name it as fbauth2.

Thats it. Just clean and run. warning wont show again.[image]

Comment: I'm running this under Xcode 7.1 but using the iPhone 6 Plus simulator running iOS 8.1. This shouldn't be appearing should it?

Answer (score 21):

As to v4.6.0 of the FaceBook SDK, add the following key into your plist file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ does `not` tell you todo this, good that you pointed it out!

Answer (score 14):

Just follow the Facebook explanation: [Preparing Your Apps for iOS9](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)
Apple mention it in their:[Privacy and Your App Keynote 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=703)

Answer (score 5):

Please just do not add this to your CFBundleURLSchemes... that will actually HIJACK any app's attempt at Facebook auth, causing a popup to show "X app wants to open " dialog...

You DO NOT want to be doing that.

cf:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios
https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2015/04/url_masques_on_apps.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/2tlx29/get_url_scheme_of_any_app
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this when running my Kiwi tests as our test target didn't have access to main bundle. So I had to add a condition to `isRegisteredCanOpenURLScheme` in `FBSDKInternalUtility.m`

```
+ (BOOL)isRegisteredCanOpenURLScheme:(NSString *)urlScheme
{
  static dispatch_once_t fetchBundleOnce;
  static NSArray *schemes = nil;

  dispatch_once(&fetchBundleOnce, ^{
    schemes = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"LSApplicationQueriesSchemes"];
    if (!schemes) { // This is a work around for our Kiwi tests as the Specs target doesn't have access to main bundle
      NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
      NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
      NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
      schemes = [dictionary valueForKey:@"LSApplicationQueriesSchemes"];
    }
  });

  return [schemes containsObject:urlScheme];
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. I could not get anything else to work. This seems odd to me that we have to edit facebooks code, won't it get erased when FB updates their cocopods.

Answer (score 1):

To build your app for iOS 9 : (  For Facebook Share )

1. Open `Info.plist` file , add another field  **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** under **Information Property List** and set it's datatype `Array` or `NSArray` .
2. Add 3 **items** for **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** and set their datatype to `String` or `NSString` .
3. Assign `fbauth2` , `fbshareextension` , `fbapi` as item value .

**Follow this photo** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Write the below code in your info.plist under the **LSApplicationQueriesScheme**

<string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
```

Comment: out of date. The newer SDK requires fewer

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code in `swift 5.0`

```
extension Bundle {
   static let externalURLSchemes: [String] = {
      guard let urlTypes = main.infoDictionary?["LSApplicationQueriesSchemes"] 
       as? [String] else {
        return []
      }
      return urlTypes
   }()
}
```

You can call using `Bundle`

```
guard Bundle.externalURLSchemes.contains(URLScheme) else {
    return
}
```