# Facebook 7.0.3 login issue on iOS 9

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ios9, facebook-unity-sdk

I have this message in the Xcode's log :

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbauth2"
```

And my app doesn't open the Facebook App, but Safari.

And then I have an error in the callback.

(Everything was ok on iOS8)

Here all the logs :

```
on clicked btn game over facebook connect
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

2015-09-18 14:42:29.386 numbersAddictL[12643:531372] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbauth2"
on clicked btn game over facebook connect
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

2015-09-18 14:42:29.391 numbersAddictL[12643:531372] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbauth2"
-> applicationWillResignActive()
FbLogInWithReadPermissions - Error Response:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 301.)

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

FbLogInWithReadPermissions - Error Response:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 301.)

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

-> applicationDidEnterBackground()
-> applicationWillEnterForeground()
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
2015-09-18 14:42:39.100 numbersAddictL[12643:531582] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: Im having similar issues.  this might help.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006033/ios-9-fbauth2-missing-from-info-plist/32525579#32525579)

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 9 (with Facebook iOS SDK )  you have add more keys to the info.plist. This error can be related to this.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>facebook.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>        
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

[Facebook getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick answer.

I still have the issue


2015-09-18 19:54:58.935 numbersAddictL[14491:638023] FBSDKLog: fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0
2015-09-18 19:54:58.939 numbersAddictL[14491:638023] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbauth2"
....
FbLogInWithReadPermissions - Error Response:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 308.)

Answer (score 0):

Look within your directory tree, and double check whose plist you are modifying. If you are running 'Tests', remember you still have to update and add additional keys to your 'main' plist (Under the Grandfather and not its descendants).Furthermore, enroll with Facebook Developers and attempt to create a 'sample beta app' for an 'existing project'. This will let you deviate, in terms of not-following a traditional development trajectory, without losing datum and the original template. :)

I found this Q&A on SO to be quite useful and perhaps relevant to your issues:
[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)