# Facebook Log In - Sigabrt Error in App Delegate and App Crashes

Tags: facebook, swift, swift2, facebook-login, ios9

I am trying to create a simple Facebook login with swift and parse. iOS9. Twitter login works fine but the Facebook login keeps crashing and no idea why? The crash leads to AppDelegate.swift saying there is a Sigabrt error "signal sigabbt"

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("MY ID", clientKey:"<MY CLIENT KEY")
        PFTwitterUtils.initializeWithConsumerKey("CONSUMER KEY", consumerSecret:"CONSUMER SECRET")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions);
    return true

}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

}

2015-09-30 18:35:46.237 Unilad[10789:3335461] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105595f65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105921deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Unilad                              0x00000001025619e7 +[FBSDKInternalUtility validateAppID] + 183
    3   Unilad                              0x0000000102561a10 +[FBSDKInternalUtility validateURLSchemes] + 32
    4   Unilad                              0x000000010258a3ae -[FBSDKLoginManager logInParametersWithPermissions:] + 78
    5   Unilad                              0x000000010258abc8 -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithBehavior:] + 88
    6   Unilad                              0x000000010258ab44 -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithPermissions:handler:] + 292
    7   Unilad                              0x0000000102588e57 -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:] + 343
    8   Unilad                              0x0000000102588cc7 -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:handler:] + 103
    9   Unilad                              0x00000001026acc90 -[PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider authenticateAsync] + 476
    10  Unilad                              0x00000001026abb60 +[PFFacebookUtils _logInAsyncWithReadPermissions:publishPermissions:] + 144
    11  Unilad                              0x00000001026ab9b5 +[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:block:] + 71
    12  Unilad                              0x00000001026c392e -[PFLogInViewController _loginWithFacebook] + 878
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103e451fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000103fa9504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000103fa97d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000103fa8906 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001042f5ca5 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 10289
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000103eaf592 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000103eb0681 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000103e62752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000103e3dfcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054c20a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054b7fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054b7483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054b6e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107077ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000103e43676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    28  Unilad                              0x000000010250e2bd main + 109
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010644392d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me 3 days ago. I updated my Parse and Facebook SDK and problem solved. Try to update your SDKs.

Comment: I am pretty new to this. Is that easy?

Comment: Parse and Facebook have great guide for add their SDK to your project. Just follow the instructions its easy.

Comment: I am using Pods and have tried updating the SDKs within the pods but still not having any luck.

Comment: think that is the crashlog?

Comment: crash log is above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your problem is very clear. App ID not found. Check your app id in your code it should be in appdelegate.

Comment: Everything in the App Delegate is above. I am pretty sure the App ID isn't there. I am following tutorials. But this is the one thing I can't figure out

Comment: I am not a comfortable place right now. So I can't help you. But you must add your App ID's in your AppDelegate. Check Parse and Facebook tutorials they will help you to add their ID's.

Comment: Figured it out in the end. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006033/ios-9-fbauth2-missing-from-info-plist