# 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'

Tags: facebook, swift2, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-3.1

Before you mark this as duplicate, please note that I have already tried all the solutions in the related questions. When I click on the Facebook login button on my app, the app crashes with this error

```
2015-10-28 18:31:05.277 retailcatalogue[96362:2057887] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'
```

I looked at the available solutions and updated my info.plist but it still doesn't work. Please help, thanks!

My info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2 </string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the space after fbauth2

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on Info.plist of your app and select "Open as Source Code". Just after the `<dict>` tag, add the following code:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
```

Now run your app and try signing to Facebook again. Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32006111/1131061).

Answer (score 0):

The versions you mention in your tags are not prepared to handle iOS 9. The solution is to download 4.7.1, latest one as of November 4th, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "fbauth2" in your plist. Just check the difference between your plist file and what they have given in the sample folder.

You need to add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" array with 4 string values.
Please check samples for reference.

It is the exact solution.