# LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and derived data

Tags: swift

I would like to open a whatsapp url in my app like.

```
let whatsAppUrl = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsAppUrl!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsAppUrl!)
}
```

I extend my info.plist with a dictionary "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" and add my url scheme for whatsapp.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<dict>
    <key>Item 0</key>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</dict>
```

If i run my app i get the following error message.

```
"This app is not allowed to query for scheme whatsapp"
```

I read some solutions with cleaning the derived data and run the app again to fix this issue. But this not help me, exists an other solution for my issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have made the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes a `dict`, it **must be an array**, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833785/1311272), then it will work :).

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

And I would also recommend you to not unwrap the optional URL using `!`, you can do it like this instead:

```
guard 
   let whatsAppUrl = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"),
   case let application = UIApplication.shared,
    application.canOpenURL(whatsAppUrl) 
else { return }
application.openURL(whatsAppUrl)
```

Comment: many thanks. now i get a new error message "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!" - error: "(null)"

Comment: hmm strange, you are sure you are using an array and not a dictionary now? maybe try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34037713/1311272, could be problems with the question mark ?

Comment: the error only appear in xcode, on my iphone is everything fine :) thanks a lot

Comment: can one info.plist have two LSApplicationQueriesSchemes ? I have fb login as well.

Answer (score 9):

```
let url = "whatsapp://send?text=Hello World!"
 if let urlString = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) {
  if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL)
        } 
       }}
```

and define query scheme like that

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```