# How can I open instagram query scheme for sharing to stories?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram-api, instagram-story

When I try to share an image to instagram stories I'm getting the following error: 
***This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram-stories***

Though I added the custom URL scheme **instagram-stories** to **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**

I followed the Instagram's documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/#ios-developers and my code is as follows:

```
private func shareToInstagramStories() {
    guard let imagePNGData = UIImage(named: "myImage").pngData() else { return }
    guard let instagramStoryUrl = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share") else { return }
    guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramStoryUrl) else { return }

    let itemsToShare: [[String: Any]] = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": imagePNGData]]
    let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]
    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(itemsToShare, options: pasteboardOptions)
    UIApplication.shared.open(instagramStoryUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

What should I for not getting the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put only `<string>instagram</string>`. It's not necessary the full path but the base of the scheme url.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Actually, instagram-stories key was necessary instead of just instagram key. But your answer inspired the dict/array dilemma for me. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I solved the error with the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393379/5061249

I was also trying to define LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as a dict :(