# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have upgraded a react-native project (RN0.30 to RN0.35) following the docs:

(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html)

Xcode 8.0 builds the project successfully however I am getting an uncaught NSException return error and the device simulator does not load up the project.

[Xcode project screenshot with error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEYe9.jpg)

I have tried deleting node_modules and re-installing them, uninstalling and reinstalling watchman, clearing the npm cache yet no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something to do with your Facebook Authentication. Check the answer to this question for more info: [iOS 9 “fbauth2” missing from Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006033/ios-9-fbauth2-missing-from-info-plist)

Comment: Ah yes, I needed to add in fb-sdk info.plist configs again. Thank you :)